# Python/Opencv - How to find the bottom left vertex of a polygon

Tags: python, opencv

Good morning,

i'm new to OpenCV and numpy and i'm trying to find a way to get one of the vertex of a polygon. I need to extract che bottom left vertex of the shape.

I get the polygon as a not ordered numpy array, let's say

```
 [[348 778]
 [313 856]
 [200 621]
 [235 558]]
```

i need to find the bottom left vertex, as in the image

[image]

i should select `[778, 348]`

Is there a way to get this vertex?

Comment: why is [313 856] the bottom _left_ vertex? I think you're confusing left and right, top and bottom, smallest and largest. please explain which way is left and right, and which way is top and bottom, and what do "smallest" and "largest" mean. I'm asking not because I'm dumb but because you contradict yourself.

Comment: thanks Cristoph, i ideated the question to be clearer

Comment: no edits have been made yet.

Answer (score 0):

To get your lower-left point, you should get the two points with the greatest y values, which represent the bottom. Then, you should get the point with the lowest corresponding x, which represents the point in the bottom left. Using your points that are represented in [y,x], you can use the following code:

```
arr_list = [[348,778], [313,856], [200,621], [235,558]]

# Sorting the points to get the greatest 2 y values
sorted_list = sorted(arr_list, reverse=True)

# If x of the greatest y is lower, return it. Else, return the other point.
if sorted_list[0][1] < sorted_list[1][1]:
    point = sorted_list[0]
else:
    point = sorted_list[1]
```